# Car rental not honouring agreed price

Tags: car-rentals, dubai, uae

Before arriving in Dubai I agreed a car rent with a rental company. Agreement included the price and some car options.

Upon arriving the person handing over the car asked for a higher price, and the discussed options weren't available. He tried to show me the messages between us with the higher price but I have the messages with the final agreed price.

I decided not to take the car as he did not honour the agreement.

Would this put me in any legal trouble? I had to send him a photocopy of my passport before arriving, but as far as I can remember I didn't sign a contract.

Comment: Did you actually make a booking?

Comment: @Traveller not through a website as I discussed the booking with the company through their WhatsApp. He might have booked me on their internal system, can't say for sure.

Comment: In other words I haven't got a booking number/reference

Comment: Is this a large international brand or a local independent?

Comment: @jcaron local independent

Comment: so you have no contract, nothing you can do. And as the rental company is never going to see you again anyway elsewhere they don't care that you now don't like them.

Answer (score 11):

**You're fine.** The agreement was that you would get car X at price Y.  On arrival, they could not keep their end of the deal, so you don't have to keep your end either.

I do have to say that this is quite unusual though: most reputable car rental companies would bend over backwards and upgrade you for free if they had any cars left, instead of letting a potential customer walk away.  I presume the price was literally too good to be true and they were just trying to pressure you into renting a more expensive mode.

Comment: Your experience is certainly different from mine. I found that most "reputable" car rental places try aggressive  upsells at the desk and that I often need to dig in hard to get them to honor the booking price (which they will typically do after dragging their feet). I even have a signed letter from my credit card company certifying they indeed provide full CDW coverage and I had to pull that letter out on occasions.  In this regard I do prefer local budget shops: they tend to do a lot less of that nonsense.

Comment: @Hilmar my experience is more in line with lambshaanxy's. If you make a reservation at one of the big places, and what you reserved is unavailable, they will provide something at the same or lower price — it may not be exactly what you wanted, but it will have at least the same passenger/cargo capacity, and if you're lucky it might be an upgrade.

Comment: @Hilmar : yes, but photoshopping the messages and trying to gaslight the customer is a lot uglier than just trying to upsell.

Comment: @Hilmar I think it depends on the location. I think certain more tourist trappy locations are more likely to pull this sort of stunts.